# Sum of previous rows based on time intervals

Tags: sql, teradata

I am unable to get the intended result table.
I have the following table:

[image: Tables]

I want the result table to have a column of revenue generated 1 YEAR ago for all the orders before that particular product was purchased. This should be based on product table.
For example the 1st record has that field as 0 since no product was ordered before that. The 2nd record has the revenue of 1st record, since 1st record was purchased in the timespan of 1 year before the 2nd record. Similarly the 3rd records contains the revenue (summation of 1st and 2nd record) as they fall in the timespan of 1 year before the 3rd record.
But the 4th record has 0 in it because no PAPERGIFT product was ordered before the 4th record. The 1st,2nd and 3rd records have PRODUCTTABLE as CARDS, so the revenue was summed.
Hence i want this to be based on the product table and the time span.
I have written the following query but it does not produce the correct output :

```
select orderserialno, prodsku, netrevenue, orderplacedtime, 

sum(netrevenue) OVER (PARTITION BY producttable, orderplacedtime - interval '365' day 
ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS REVENUE_BEFORE1YEAR

from scratch.net_revenue where userid ='001042874727'
```

Any corrections in the above query to get the correct output will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: You might need an ORDER BY in your OVER

Comment: Order by what? I tried order by orderplacedtime but that does not work

Comment: What ouput are you getting from your current query? And what are you trying to do with this part of your partition:  `orderplacedtime - interval '365' day`?  That's not going to constrain that calculation to only 1 year, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes i am trying to constrain the revenue for every purchase to the last one year before that product was purchased. My current query gives the result table having the REVENUE_BEFORE1YEAR field values same as the NETREVENUE. So i donot want that. I want the field values as shown in the result table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a derived table to accomplish this, as far as I know.  The derived table will get the max date for each ProductTable. Then you'll join to that so that you only get the rows in the time frame you're looking for.  Something along these lines:

```
select
...
sum(nr.netrevenue) over (partition by producttable 
  order by nr.orderplacedtime rows unbounded preceding)
from
scratch.net_revenue nr
inner join 
(
select
ProductTable,
max(orderplacedtime) as MaxOrderTime
from
scratch.net_revenue
group by 1) t
on nr.orderplacedtime between (t.maxordertime - interval '365' day) and t.maxordertime
and nr.producttable = t.producttable
```